# sql-workbench encontrar registro que no se repite en dos tablas

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Buenas a todos...
A ver quien me puede ayudar con esta consulta simple...
Tengo una base de datos formula 1, en ella hay dos tablas, una es coches y la otra participacion, la tabla participacion tiene la clave(codigoCoche) foranea de coches que participaron en carreras en ciertos años.
Lo que me piden es basicamente que haga una consulta que muestre solo los coches que no participaron en una carrera. He hecho esta pero no se ejecuta..

```
SELECT codiCotxe
  FROM formula1.Cotxe
 WHERE not in(SELECT codiCotxe from formula1.Participació);
```

Estas son las tabla coche
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la tabla participacion
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracuas de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falta el nombre de la columna antes del `NOT IN`:

```
WHERE codiCotxe NOT IN(...
```

De forma alternativa, puedes usar `NOT EXISTS`, que por veces puede resultar en mejor rendimiento para este tipo de consultas:

```
SELECT c.codiCotxe
  FROM formula1.Cotxe c
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                     FROM formula1.Participació p
                    WHERE p.codiCotxe = c.codiCotxe)
```

Comment: Tienes razon, me funciono, muchas gracias